# Creating a connection using excel-vba

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

here's what I'm trying to do and I'm trying to automate it all in excel vba.

I'm tying to create a connection if it hasn't been already created, run a specific SQL command, throw down the table in my "Data" spreadsheet.

Afterwords I'll do manipulation on it.

The reason I want to do it in VBA is because when I tried just manually doing the connection it would get deleted and the end user would have to reset it up. I want this to be as easy as possible for the end user. The other thing I notice is that; aside from not giving me the table [I don't think I told it to yet] is that it pops up with the default table dialog.

```
Workbooks("Tool4.xlsm").Connections.AddFromFile _
    "C:\Users\Cutting_This_Out.odc" _
    , True, False
With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("255.255.255.0").OLEDBConnection
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .Connection = _
    "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated " _
    & "Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=255.255.255.0; " _
    & "Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation " _
    & "ID=TRIMMED-PC;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=COSTrpt"
    .CommandText = _
    "SELECT [PRVDR_NUM],[hha2011cbsa_ms].CBSA,[CBSA_Name],[VISITS_IN],[ADJUSTED_REIMB] FROM [COSTrpt].[dbo].[hha2011cbsa_ms] INNER JOIN  wage_index ON wage_index.CBSA = hha2011cbsa_ms.CBSA"
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .SavePassword = False
    .SourceConnectionFile = ""
    .SourceDataFile = ""
    .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
    .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
End With
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("255.255.255.0").Refresh
End Sub
```

Other information; I'm connecting with MS-SQL-Server and I've trimmed some private info out of that.

Comment: What is the specific question you are asking? Does the code work, despite requesting a table? If not, is there an error message that you should post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question here at [social-msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c822a9cc-2ebf-4596-862f-bfa78dc11601/execute-a-odc-connection-within-excel-from-vb2008). The step that you are missing is to use `QueryTables.Add` to get the data into a worksheet (although your question is not entirely clear).